# Problem passing https address to WebRequest

Tags: .net, https, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

This code has been working for years to connect to an API service. I assume they recently changed something at server level. Using .NET Framework 4.72.

```
Dim url As String = "https://example.com/xxx"
Dim PageRequest As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
PageResponse = PageRequest.GetResponse
```

I get an error 426.

OK. At this point, if I debug, PageRequest.Address returns:
"**http**://example.com/xxx" not **https**.

Looks like it is not connecting using TLS.
What am I missing?

NOTE: if I paste the url in a browser, the server does respond correctly and displays the data I am looking for.

TIA

Comment: Have you compared your application's TLS support and the website's TLS requirement? It might happen that your client supports for example at most TLS 1.2 but the website requires 1.3

Comment: Most of the time the http response's body contains some hint which part of the request is incompatible with the service. Please check that as well.

Comment: @PeterCsala Unfortunately it doesn't contain any hint. I've tried to explicitly use TLS 1.2 then 1.3 to no avail (which is the default in .NET 4.72 anyway) :-(